# mysql client port

Tags: mysql, connection, port

I'm connecting to a remote MySQL server (on the default port 3306) using the C API call [`mysql_real_connect()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-real-connect.html).

1. How can I discover which TCP port is used on the client host?
2. Is it possible to specify the port that I wish to use?

Comment: a tcp connection is used

Comment: @ArunKillu - not necessarily, you can change this behavior by using `MYSQL_OPT_PROTOCOL or MYSQL_OPT_NAMED_PIPE` as argument to `mysql_options()`

Comment: @KristerAndersson 10x for that piece of info i will more in to it

Answer (score 0):

### 1

You can use `lsof`.
Type following in your shell:

```
$ lsof | grep TCP
```

And then look for the port on which your mysql server is listening.

You can also make use of `netstat`.
Details can be found by `man netstat`.

### 2

As far as I know, you can not.

Comment: The question was about the client not the server port.

Comment: Because it is client port, you need to `lsof` to find out the port number the OS has assigned. If it were server port, you already know the port number server is listening to.

Answer (score 0):

the MYSQL structure has an FD buried in it (for me at least; tested on centos7 with mariadb 5.5.58).
you can use that to find the local address and port

```
struct sockaddr_in laddr;
socklen_t sb = sizeof(laddr);
if (getsockname(mysql.net.fd, (sockaddr*)&laddr, &sb) == -1)
    printf("getsockname() failed, err %s\n",strerror(errno));
else
    printf("local address [%x] port [%u]",ntohl(laddr.sin_addr.s_addr),ntohs(laddr.sin_port));
```